# Android studio on a react native project Process 'command 'npx'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

My android studio is not building my project. I don't understand why because not much has changed in my project since the last time it worked. I have tried ./gradlew clean

Answer (score 0):

I was declaring a constant twice on my code and couldn't see the proper debug error through the release from android studio to find out